# Thorough analysis of Kant's "conditions of possibility"

Tags: metaphysics, kant, analytic-philosophy

Is anyone aware of a thorough (mathematical) treatment/analysis of the concept of Kant's "Bedingungen der Möglichkeit"  of something ([conditions of possibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_of_possibility))?

I thought about it in the following context:

> Which conditions must the rules of a [cellular automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton) fulfill
>   such that phenomenon X can arise/emerge (from some initial
>   conditions)?

(Phenomenon X = e.g. the existence of [autopoietic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autopoietic_system) [systems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.2.2757))

But that's a very restricted context. I am looking for a general treatment.

Comment: Thorough (mathy) analysis of contingent posterior synthetic phenomenal conditions of possibility doesn’t exist since this is the task of empirical science. As for the synthetic a priori, this is the task of mathematical logic including reverse mathematics a la axioms synthesis. The substantial form capable of autopsies of cellular automata possibly needs inspiration from both…

Comment: Also included in the non-contingent thorough analysis could be lossless compression where a set of necessary and sufficient constraints reproduce the conceived sense data in the sense that condition of possibility is nothing but compression…